# Documentation on spatial queries

Tags: select-by-location, within

Is there any documentation / definition of the operations within, crosses, intersects etc that can be found on the spatial query just like ArcGIS provide?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is [The Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM):

> The matrix provides an approach for classifying geometry relations.
>   Roughly speaking, with a true/false matrix domain, there are 512
>   possible 2D topologic relations, that can be grouped into binary
>   classification schemes. For English speakers, there are about 10
>   schemes (relations) that have a name that reflects their semantics
>   (e.g. "Intersects", "Touches", "Equals", and others.) When testing two
>   geometries against a scheme, the result of this test is a spatial
>   predicate named by the scheme.

Comment: Hi there. I am aware of the matrix, my question is, is it mentioned anywhere in the QGIS Documentation that it is the one that is used? Can I verify that QGIS uses these definitions?

Comment: @VasilisKaloyirou There is no mention of QGIS in your question.

Comment: Oh yes excuse me I rushed my question and I just wrote about the spatial query, meaning the spatial query plugin in QGIS.

Comment: @VasilisKaloyirou To get your question re-opened you will need to [edit] your question to make what you are asking more explicit as per your comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dill delete it shortly and then re-ask about the issue.